# oracle: how to convert string like '2000-01-01T01:01:01' to Date?

Tags: java, oracle, date

In pl/sql,

`select to_date('2012-01-01T12:01:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss') from dual;`

works.

But when using in java,

`String sql = "select to_date('2012-01-01T12:01:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd\"T\"hh24:mi:ss') from dual";`

does not work.

Please give me a hand.

error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-10-31T13:16:38"
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:263)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:253)
  ...

    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:719)
    at dao.UserManagerNB.getData(UserManagerNB.java:64)
    at dao.UserManagerNB.editApplianceApplication(UserManagerNB.java:92)
    at com.svse.servlet.PutAppJsonServlet.doGet(PutAppJsonServlet.java:80)
  ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-10-31T13:16:38"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextLong(JsonReader.java:975)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$8.read(TypeAdapters.java:261)
    ... 30 more
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ron, what error are you getting? 
You have to use double-quotes " "  to enclose a string in Java.

So your code should be:

```
String sql = "select to_date('2012-01-01T12:01:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd\"T\"hh24:mi:ss') from dual";
```